# Как в Angular создавать тег select зависящий от выбора в другом?

Tags: angular

Подскажите как правильно реализовать связь двух тегов select.
У меня есть вот такой набор данных.

```
simpleArr = [
{fighter: 'Scorpion', variations: ['Ninjutsu', 'Hellfire', 'Inferno']},
{fighter: 'Sub-Zero', variations: ['Cryomancer', 'Unbreakable', 'Grandmaster']},
{fighter: 'Raiden', variations: ['Thunder God', 'Displacer', 'Master of Storms']},
{fighter: 'Liu Kang', variations: ['Flame Fist', 'Dragons Fire', 'Dualist']},
{fighter: 'Ermac', variations: ['Mystic', 'Spectral', 'Master of Souls']}
];
```

В один select выводится fighter в другой надо выводить его variations. 
Я создал пустой массив в классе и в методе

```
CheckValue(obj): void {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.simpleArr.length; i++) {
    if (obj === this.simpleArr[i].fighter) {
        this.arr = this.simpleArr[i].variations;
    }
  }
}
```

По событию с шаблона компонента получаю значение fighter и закидываю variations в пустой массив.
Вот ссылка на [песочницу](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-akgyvy).

Может есть другие способы связи или же этот сойдет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблема еще заключается в том, что перед тем, как пользователь первый раз выберет файтера - массив вариаций пустой:

```
export class AppComponent {
    simpleArr = ....
    arr = this.simpleArr[0].variations;
}
```

Также вы делаете проверку по названии файтера, это не совсем правильно, потому что представьте ситуацию, что может быть так, что в массиве есть несколько файтеров с таким именем, для избежания этого есть старая связка `ngValue + ngModel`:

```
<label for="">Fighter</label>
<select [ngModel]="selectedFighter" (ngModelChange)="CheckValue($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let f of simpleArr" [ngValue]="f">{{f.fighter}}</option>
</select>
<label for="">Variation</label>
<select>
  <option *ngFor = "let v of arr">{{v}}</option>
</select>
```

Не забываем регистрировать `FormsModule` для доступа к этим директивам:

```
// app.module.ts

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    imports: [..., FormsModule]
})
export class ...
```

Все, что нам нужно это создать модель в компоненте и немного подрихтовать метод:

```
export class AppComponent {
    simpleArr = ...
    arr = this.simpleArr[0].variations;

    public selectedFighter = this.simpleArr[0];

    CheckValue(fighter) {
        this.arr = fighter.variations;
    }
}
```

Заметьте, вам даже не нужно делать проверку в цикле и искать нужного файтера по имени.

Comment: Спасибо. Избавили меня от велосипедостроения:)

Answer (score 1):

Можно например вот так, вообще без методов:

```
<label for="">Fighter</label>
  <select [(ngModel)]="idx">
    <option 
      *ngFor="let f of simpleArr; let i = index"
      [ngValue]="i"
    >
      {{f.fighter}}
    </option>
  </select>

<label for="">Variation</label>
  <select>
    <option 
      *ngFor = "let v of simpleArr[idx].variations"
    >
      {{v}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

В контроллере инициализировать idx = 0;